# What are implicit objects?

Tags: scala, implicit

I was reading about [type classes](http://danielwestheide.com/blog/2013/02/06/the-neophytes-guide-to-scala-part-12-type-classes.html) where implicit objects were mentioned:

```
object Math {
  trait NumberLike[T] {
    def plus(x: T, y: T): T
    def divide(x: T, y: Int): T
    def minus(x: T, y: T): T
  }
  object NumberLike {
    implicit object NumberLikeDouble extends NumberLike[Double] {
      def plus(x: Double, y: Double): Double = x + y
      def divide(x: Double, y: Int): Double = x / y
      def minus(x: Double, y: Double): Double = x - y
    }
    implicit object NumberLikeInt extends NumberLike[Int] {
      def plus(x: Int, y: Int): Int = x + y
      def divide(x: Int, y: Int): Int = x / y
      def minus(x: Int, y: Int): Int = x - y
    }
  }
}
```

What are they? Where are they described? I only found definition of implicit classes on the [web](http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/core/implicit-classes.html) but not of implicit objects.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

In Scala, objects and values are treated mostly the same. An implicit object can be thought of as a value which is found in the process of looking up an implicit of its type.

In your example, if one implicitly looks for a `NumberLike` type class with type parameter `Double` or `Int`, one will find `NumberLikeDouble` and `NumberLikeInt`.

```
implicit object NumberLikeDouble extends NumberLike[Double]
```

is thus roughly the same as

```
implicit val NumberLikeDouble: NumberLike[Double] = new NumberLike[Double] { ...}
```

or

```
implicit def NumberLikeDouble: NumberLike[Double] = new NumberLike[Double] { ...}
```

Like a `val`, there is only a single value of that type and instantiation is not needed.

---

A simple use case:

```
import Math.NumberLike

def sum[A](x: A, y: A)(implicit nl: NumberLike[A]) = nl.plus(x, y)

sum(4, 5)   // finds NumberLikeInt
```

Comment: Is there any difference between the implicit val and implicit def equivalent declarations ? Or are the three implicit declarations (implicit object, def, val) completely interchangeable ?

Comment: The `object` and `val` variants create the value only once, whereas with `def` you would instantiate the `NumberLike` each time it is looked up. For a stateless type class (no value or type parameters) it therefore makes more sense to use `object` or `val`. The `object` creates a "proper" class, so to say, whereas the `val` in this case creates an anonymous sub-class.

Comment: Thanks for clarification, so object and val are completely equivalent in all respect?

Comment: Unless you add members to the type. For example, `val Foo = new { def bar = 33 }`. If you call `Foo.bar`, Scala must use runtime reflection to handle that method, and it is deprecated. In those cases, using `object Foo { def bar = 33 }` creates a "real" class description including that method.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to implicit objects, you can define:

```
def mymethod[T : NumberLike](value: T): T = {
  implicitly[NumberLike[T]].plus(value, value)
}
```

which allows you to call your methods on Double and Floats because you have objects to deal with them.

```
scala> mymethod(1.0)
res0: Double = 2.0

scala> mymethod(2)
res0: Int = 4

scala> mymethod("test") //Error
```