# Filter from Seq less/greater elements and only one equal

Tags: scala, scala-collections

I want to implement method in Scala which filters from Seq elements which are for example greater than provided value and additionally returns up to one equal element. For example:

```
greaterOrEqual(Seq(1,2,3,3,4), 3) shouldBe Seq(3,4)
```

I ended up with such method:

```
def greaterOrEqual(
      seq: ArrayBuffer[Long],
      value: Long
  ): ArrayBuffer[Long] = {
    val greater = seq.filter(_ > value)
    val equal = seq.filter(_ == value)
    if (equal.isEmpty) {
      greater
    } else {
      equal.tail ++ greater
    }
  }
```

but somehow it doesn't look nice to me :) Moreover, I'd like to have generic version of this method where I'd able to use not only Long type but custom case classes.

Do you have any suggestions? 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can get rid of the `if` and do `equal.take(1) ++ greater`. This works for empty `equal` too. Or even better, `val equal = seq.find(_ == value).toList` and then just `equal ++ greater`

Answer (score 2):

```
def foo[A : Ordering[A]](seq: Seq[A], value: A) = seq.find(_ == value).toList ++ seq.filter(implicitly[Ordering[A]].gt(_,value))
```

Or (different style)

```
def foo[A](seq: Seq[A], value: A)(implicit ord: Ordering[A]) = {
   import ord._
   seq.find(_ == value).toList ++ seq.filter(_ > value)
}
```

The code below is deprecated

```
scala> def foo[A <% Ordered[A]](seq: Seq[A], value: A) = seq.find(_ == value).toList ++  seq.filter(_ > value)
foo: [A](seq: Seq[A], value: A)(implicit evidence$1: A => Ordered[A])List[A]

scala> foo(Seq(1,2,3,3,4,4,5),3)
res8: List[Int] = List(3, 4, 4, 5)
```

Comment: this seems like what I needed. Thanks. I just wonder if I want to use this function with case class, which has a numeric field I want to compare to, so I have to overload `>` operator for this class, don't I?

Comment: It seems you need to define implicit Ordering for your case class, something like `// sort by age
   implicit object AgeOrdering extends Ordering[Person] {
     def compare(a:Person, b:Person) = a.age compare b.age
   }` . See here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22592456/what-are-implicit-objects

Comment: No, my mistake, you just need to extend Ordered  `case class Bar(i: Int) extends Ordered[Bar] {
  def compare(that: Bar) = i.compare(that.i)
}

scala> foo(Seq(Bar(1),Bar(2)),Bar(2))
res12: List[Bar] = List(Bar(2))`

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez Ok, I will strike it out. Can you show how to use Ordering typeclass approach in this case?

Answer (score 1):

Here's my take on it (preserving original order).

```
import scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer

def greaterOrEqual[A]( seq :ArrayBuffer[A], value :A
                     )(implicit ord :Ordering[A]
                      ) : ArrayBuffer[A] =
  seq.foldLeft((ArrayBuffer.empty[A],true)){
    case (acc, x)        if ord.lt(x,value) => acc
    case ((acc,bool), x) if ord.gt(x,value) => (acc :+ x, bool)
    case ((acc,true), x)                    => (acc :+ x, false)
    case (acc, _)                           => acc
  }._1
```

testing:

```
greaterOrEqual(ArrayBuffer.from("xawbaxbt"), 'b')
//res0: ArrayBuffer[Char] = ArrayBuffer(x, w, b, x, t)
```

Answer (score 1):

This is an excellent problem for a simple tail-recursive algorithm over lists.

```
def greaterOrEqual[T : Ordering](elements: List[T])(value: T): List[T] = {
  import Ordering.Implicits._

  @annotation.tailrec
  def loop(remaining: List[T], alreadyIncludedEqual: Boolean, acc: List[T]): List[T] =
    remaining match {
      case x :: xs =>
        if (!alreadyIncludedEqual && x == value)
          loop(remaining = xs, alreadyIncludedEqual = true, x :: acc)
        else if (x > value)
          loop(remaining = xs, alreadyIncludedEqual, x :: acc)
        else
          loop(remaining = xs, alreadyIncludedEqual, acc)

      case Nil =>
        acc.reverse
    }

  loop(remaining = elements, alreadyIncludedEqual = false, acc = List.empty)
}
```

Which you can use like this:

```
greaterOrEqual(List(1, 3, 2, 3, 4, 0))(3)
// val res: List[Int] = List(3, 4)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below snippet:

```
val list = Seq(1,2,3,3,4)
val value = 3

list.partition(_>=3)._1.toSet.toSeq
```

Here partition method divide the list into two list. First list which satisfy the given condition, and second list contains the remaining elements.

Comment: It will de-duplicate elements greater than `value` too

Comment: Yes, that is what the output of the question demands. If you want not to remove duplicates, you can just skip doing "toSet"

Comment: No, it seems de-duping is required only for elements equal to `value`. At least that's what the code does

Comment: equal.tail can be a list and can have more than one equal values.

Comment: You are right. Then I don't know what was the original requirement

Comment: hmm, I wanted to dedup elements only equal to `value`.  But, indeed, the tail can have more that one value. Probably a bug in my code.

Answer (score 0):

For generic method you can using implicit `Ordering`. Any type who can compare elements can be handled by `greaterOrEqual` method.

```
import scala.math.Ordering._

def greaterOrEqual[T](seq: Seq[T], value: T)(implicit ordering: Ordering[T]): Seq[T] = {
  @scala.annotation.tailrec
  def go(xs: List[T], value: T, acc: List[T]): List[T] = {
    xs match {
      case Nil => acc
      case head :: rest if ordering.compare(head, value) == 0 => rest.foldLeft(head :: acc){
        case (result, x) if ordering.compare(x, value) > 0 => x :: result
        case (result, _) => result
      }
      case head :: rest if ordering.compare(head, value) > 0 => go(rest, value, head :: acc)
      case _ :: rest => go(rest, value, acc)
    }
  }
  go(seq.toList, value, List.empty[T]).reverse
}
```

Comment: Appending to any Seq may be very inefficient. I would just use Lists and prepend instead.